# Android SurfaceView destroys after minimizing?

Tags: android

I use a SurfaceView and implement SurfaceHolder.Callback in order to determine if the view is created/destroyed. I'm wondering if there's anyway to stop it from destroying when I turn off the screen or switch to a different application?

I use SurfaceView for the game I'm making and I don't want the application to restart every time someone turns off the screen and turns it back on. I would rather the application just pick up where it left off.

I'm sorry if I'm being vague so let me know if I need to provide any more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoiding the destruction of a `SurfaceView` when leaving the an `Activity` isn't really a good strategy. As is indicated in the [Activity Lifecycle documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) pausing your activity is really about pausing the game, not locking your `Activity` in the foreground.

With a well designed [Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter) of your game world you can pause instantly and resume at a reasonable place, with all the game rendered when going back. After all who wants to lose a game just because of a phone call?